# MVC daily scheduled data read from an Excel with Quartz.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I have an Excel file that is dropped to specific location on the local network every day, from which I am looking to read some data and view it in my MVC ASP.NET application.

I just wanted to confirm that I'm on the right track for tackling this task with Quartz.NET. There seems to be mixed opinions as to scheduled tasks not belonging into an MVC application?

What I'm trying to accomplish: Everyday at 00:00:

- Read excel file from network location
- Write the data to database to view on the web app.

**Edit:**

For anyone looking to set a scheduled task on their MVC, Quartz.NET was really simple to implement. Complete details on [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net).

Comment: I am not sure what your actual question is but if you are wondering if you should use Quartz.net, only you can decide that based on your environment and requirements.  We have chosen to use [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) to accomplish exactly what it seems you are trying to accomplish.  We also made sure to setup the [Auto-Start ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series) feature using the always running mode in IIS.

Comment: Thank you. I will check out Hangfire as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run scheduled tasks like this in MVC, you have to make sure, that the web application (app pool) is alive and running. IIS recycles the app pool after 20 minutes by default, if no request is made, so the MVC application will be stopped. Which might be the case when your scheduled task supposed to run. This behavior can be modified in IIS Manager at the application pools advanced settings (Idle Time-out (minutes) and Idle Time-out Action).

In [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/) you can set the website to be Always On or you can use some external service to keep IIS from recycling the app pool, like [Uptime Robot](https://uptimerobot.com/).

The best solution depends on your infrastructure and possibilities.